# hashtype encoded to base identitfcation request

Tags: hash-functions

My fault was creating this thread on cryptography subdomain forum, and those guys adviced me to ask you here < so:
0

I have surfed allover hashcat "hashtypes" page, also used some online checkers which say this hashtype is some "Cisco Type 7" mode, but I got doubts about this. The hash come as base64 encoded string :

`ABAnAAB8Ksf/5H4Tk2HavNzPESyUiz5WmRMFENal4otqLmJjAGf0PgM=

Base to hex gives this

```
00102700007c2ac7ffe47e139361dabcdccf112c948b3e5699130510d6a5e28b6a2e62630067f43e03
```

And hashed password is

P@rtner1997
All such a Base encoded strings are decoded into 82 character hashes, which got 0010270000 prefix , and if we do not count in the prefix , it is 72 char. length.

```
0010270000467b8c38683256608f7e6ad2e618d1993c59325d61c9cd77a50e9c1f3a3e145dea760131

0010270000cc5e5c62bc1861f2ca862ef2d20cca528e62406b417d62f54fc530acb1abafae69cab6df
```